# Automated predictive model fitting with variables chosen based on accessory data frame

Tags: r, linear-regression

How can I code a FOR loop (or some other function) to refit linear models?

I am performing an exhaustive search of multiple linear regression models with the R package leaps. The package does return vectors of certain fit statistics (i.e. BIC and r-squared). However, there are a few other fit criteria (i.e. CCC) I would like to generate for a subset of the models (~100). Instead of fitting the subset of models manually, I want to leverage a data.frame provided by leaps for automated refitting of predictive multiple linear models.

I have two data.frames to use: 1) the data (response + all explanatory variables) and 2) a data.frame describing what variables where in each model. The second data.frame has boolean (TRUE/FALSE) indicators of whether each explanatory variable (columns) was incorporated in the linear model (rows). Below is a representation of that data.frame.

```
     (Intercept)    var1  var2 var3   
X5          TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE 
X6          TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE 
X7.2        TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE 
X7.4        TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE 
X8.2        TRUE    TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `lapply` across the boolean data frame building formulas dynamically from `TRUE` columns. Be sure to adjust *response* to actual variable in below string.

```
model_list <- lapply(1:nrow(bool_df), function(i) {    
    tmp <- as.vector(bool_df[i,-1])
    eq <- paste("response ~ ", 
                paste(names(tmp)[tmp == TRUE], collapse=" + "))

    lm(as.formula(eq), data_df)
})
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/IANVF76496) *(building formulas only)*